# Module parameters in main tab

Tags: module, module-params

When creating Joomla modules, I use something like this in my XML manifest file to add parameters:

```
<config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="options" label="My Parameters">
                <field
                    name="my_field"
                    type="text"
                    label="Example label"
                    description="Example description"
                    default="Default value">
                </field>
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
</config>
```

This creates a new tab called "My Parameters" in the module editor, where my fields are displayed.

But how can I add fields directly to the main tab ("Module"-tab)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `<fieldset name="basic">` instead of `<fieldset name="options" label="My Parameters">`

Then name of fieldset must be **basic** otherwise it will create a new tab.